# Issue with accessing json nodes from C#

Tags: c#, json, sql-server

I have a json file that needs to be saved as sql server table. This is test.json that has Student details with coursework.

```
[{
    "Studentid": "001006360",
    "Grade": "2",
    "ExtraWork": {
        "TopRecommended": ["000133692",
        "102067155",
        "887273865"],
        "OtherCourses": ["228963647",
        "138909237",
        "899791144",
        "216165613",
        "113239563"]
    },
    "Courses": [{
        "smalldesc": "this is a test ",
        "Details": {
            "description": "Summary of the course",
            "collegeCode": "32466"
        }
    },
    {
        "smalldesc": "Second test",
        "Details": {
            "description": "Business- Course Summary",
            "collegeCode": "32469"
        }
    }]
}]
```

Below is the C# program.
I do not know how to access "smalldesc" and "collegeCode".

```
var jsonText = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test.json");    
var ser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jsonText);
for (int i = 0; i < ser.Count; i++)
{
    string Studentid = ser[i].Studentid;
    string  Grade = ser[i].Grade;

    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Course>>(jsonText);
    for (int k = 0; k < result.Count; k++)
    {
        string smalldesc = result[k].smalldesc;
        string collegeCode = result[k].Details.collegeCode;
    }
}
```

Json object class definition:

```
public class ExtraWork
{
    public List<string> TopRecommended { get; set; }
    public List<string> OtherCourses { get; set; }
}

public class Details
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string collegeCode { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public string smalldesc { get; set; }
    public Details Details { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string Studentid { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
    public ExtraWork ExtraWork { get; set; }
    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

what's the best way to save to sql server tables.

Comment: are you familiar with WebApi and or Ajax Post..? you can do it hat way if you know how to pass in parameters to your ajax web method properly..

Comment: Why deserializing again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
var ser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jsonText);
```

Is *already* doing all the deserialization for you, there is no need to call it again inside a loop.

Your code can be as simple as this:

```
var ser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jsonText);
foreach (var s in ser)
{
    string Studentid = s.Studentid;
    string  Grade = s.Grade;

    foreach(var course in ser.Courses)
    {  
        string smalldesc = course .smalldesc;
        string details = course .Details.collegeCode;
    }
}
```

FYI: using a `foreach` loop is much simpler to work with when iterating a collection (assuming your collection type implements `IEnumerable` which most of the included collections will).